# Compute Correlation Dataframe for each Vector Row by Index Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pearson-correlation

I have a dataframe with 500 columns indexed by date, with four years of data.

| Date | A | AAL | AAP | AAPL | ABC ......

| 1/2/2004  | 18.442521     |25.954398  |1.38449    |11.528444......

| 1/5/2004  | 18.922795     |25.718507  |1.442394   |11.919131...

| 1/6/2004  | 19.518334     |26.177538  |1.437189   |11.870028....

.
.
. etc...

I would like to calculate the Pearson correlation matrix for each day, so each row. I want to save the matrices by date, in the most space efficient manner readable by R. (Right now my goal is separate sheets, by index date, in Excel. I am open to suggestions.)

I have tried several ways, but this seemed the most promising, because I could not apply the corr() to a df.groupby.

However this method returned empty dataframes, and now I am stuck!
I am looking for a method that doesn't involve iteration.

```
def do_Corr(df_group):
"""Apply the function to each group in the data and return one result."""
X = df_group.corr()
return X

df.groupby([df.index.year,df.index.month,df.index.day]).apply(do_Corr).dropna()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what kind of correlation matrixes you want to produce. What does it mean "I want to save the matrices by date"? You want one matrix for each date? If yes, what are vectors? (If you fix a date, you have just one row, right?) Could you please provide more specific description, like e.g. very short version of the dataframe and a calculations you want to perform (probably with loops, etc., just to make us understand what it the goal).

Comment: Yes, one matrix for each date. The vectors would be that one row- for example: on 1/4/2004 (18.442521, 25.954398 , 1.38449 , 11.528444, ....), where each value corresponds to a different stock price.  

There is a very short version of the dataframe already in the question!

Comment: One row is one vector, right? To calculate a correlation, you need two vectors. To calculate correlation matrix, you need several vectors. So I still don't understand what are you trying to calculate.

Comment: Pearson's correlation is basically a cosine of an angle between two vectors.

Comment: I understand. My question is: do you know how to use Pandas Dataframes to calculate the correlation on a per row basis, using the .corr() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `df.T.corr()`. `.T` transposes the dataframe, so rows becomes columns, then you can apply `.corr()` method.

Comment: Thank you for your help!